# Sorting with $in not returning all docs

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following query.

```
db.getCollection('logs').find({'uid.$id': { 
    '$in': [
        ObjectId("580e3397812de36b86d68c04"),
        ObjectId("580e33a9812de36b86d68c0b"),
        ObjectId("580e339a812de36b86d68c09"),
        ObjectId("580e339a812de36b86d68c08"),
        ObjectId("580e33a9812de36b86d68c0a"),
        ObjectId("580e33bd812de36b86d68c11"),
        ObjectId("580e33c0812de36b86d68c13")
    ]}, levelno: { '$gte': 10 }
}).sort({_id: 1})
```

This should return 1847 documents. However, when executing it, I only get 1000 documents, which is the cursor's `batchSize` and then the cursor closes (setting its `cursorId` to 0), as if all documents were returned.

If I take out the sorting, then I get all 1847 documents.

So my question is, why does it silently fail when using sorting with the `$in` operator?

**EDIT**

Using `explain` gives the following output

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "session.logs",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [ 
                {
                    "levelno" : {
                        "$gte" : 10
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "uid.$id" : {
                        "$in" : [ 
                            ObjectId("580e3397812de36b86d68c04"), 
                            ObjectId("580e339a812de36b86d68c08"), 
                            ObjectId("580e339a812de36b86d68c09"), 
                            ObjectId("580e33a9812de36b86d68c0a"), 
                            ObjectId("580e33a9812de36b86d68c0b"), 
                            ObjectId("580e33bd812de36b86d68c11"), 
                            ObjectId("580e33c0812de36b86d68c13")
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "_id" : 1
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "uid.$id" : 1,
                            "levelno" : 1,
                            "_id" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "uid.$id_1_levelno_1__id_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "uid.$id" : [ 
                                "[ObjectId('580e3397812de36b86d68c04'), ObjectId('580e3397812de36b86d68c04')]", 
                                "[ObjectId('580e339a812de36b86d68c08'), ObjectId('580e339a812de36b86d68c08')]", 
                                "[ObjectId('580e339a812de36b86d68c09'), ObjectId('580e339a812de36b86d68c09')]", 
                                "[ObjectId('580e33a9812de36b86d68c0a'), ObjectId('580e33a9812de36b86d68c0a')]", 
                                "[ObjectId('580e33a9812de36b86d68c0b'), ObjectId('580e33a9812de36b86d68c0b')]", 
                                "[ObjectId('580e33bd812de36b86d68c11'), ObjectId('580e33bd812de36b86d68c11')]", 
                                "[ObjectId('580e33c0812de36b86d68c13'), ObjectId('580e33c0812de36b86d68c13')]"
                            ],
                            "levelno" : [ 
                                "[10.0, inf.0]"
                            ],
                            "_id" : [ 
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ 
            {
                "stage" : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "levelno" : 1,
                                "_id" : 1,
                                "uid.$id" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "levelno_1__id_1_uid.$id_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "levelno" : [ 
                                    "[10.0, inf.0]"
                                ],
                                "_id" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "uid.$id" : [ 
                                    "[ObjectId('580e3397812de36b86d68c04'), ObjectId('580e3397812de36b86d68c04')]", 
                                    "[ObjectId('580e339a812de36b86d68c08'), ObjectId('580e339a812de36b86d68c08')]", 
                                    "[ObjectId('580e339a812de36b86d68c09'), ObjectId('580e339a812de36b86d68c09')]", 
                                    "[ObjectId('580e33a9812de36b86d68c0a'), ObjectId('580e33a9812de36b86d68c0a')]", 
                                    "[ObjectId('580e33a9812de36b86d68c0b'), ObjectId('580e33a9812de36b86d68c0b')]", 
                                    "[ObjectId('580e33bd812de36b86d68c11'), ObjectId('580e33bd812de36b86d68c11')]", 
                                    "[ObjectId('580e33c0812de36b86d68c13'), ObjectId('580e33c0812de36b86d68c13')]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, 
            {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [ 
                        {
                            "levelno" : {
                                "$gte" : 10
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "uid.$id" : {
                                "$in" : [ 
                                    ObjectId("580e3397812de36b86d68c04"), 
                                    ObjectId("580e339a812de36b86d68c08"), 
                                    ObjectId("580e339a812de36b86d68c09"), 
                                    ObjectId("580e33a9812de36b86d68c0a"), 
                                    ObjectId("580e33a9812de36b86d68c0b"), 
                                    ObjectId("580e33bd812de36b86d68c11"), 
                                    ObjectId("580e33c0812de36b86d68c13")
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "_id_",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "isUnique" : true,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "_id" : [ 
                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: @JohnnyHK i've added the `uid.$id_1_levelno_1__id_1` index as well, but makes no difference to the returned number of docs

Comment: I added the output to the question

Comment: seems also related to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7267 but they say it was fixed

Comment: After thinking about this some more, unfortunately you cannot index this sorted query because you're sorting on a field that isn't in the query, and the query doesn't include equality conditions on all of the prefix keys that precede the sort key. See docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/).

Comment: still, this isn't related to the use (or lack of) of an index, right?

Comment: It is, because if an index can't be used, then the sort must be done in-memory and is limited to 32MB. That's why you're not getting all your docs back. The workaround would be to do this with `aggregate` instead where you can set `allowDiskUse` to true.

Comment: oh i see. Would you mind writing it down to an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that this sorted query must be performed in-memory as it's not supported by an index, and this limits the results to 32 MB. This behavior is documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/), with a JIRA about addressing this [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7694).

Furthermore, you *can't* define an index to support this query as you're sorting on a field that isn't part of the query, and neither of these cases apply:

> If the sort keys correspond to the index keys or an index prefix,
>   MongoDB can use the index to sort the query results. A *prefix* of a
>   compound index is a subset that consists of one or more keys at the
>   start of the index key pattern.

...

> An index can support sort operations on a non-prefix subset of the
>   index key pattern. To do so, the query must include **equality**
>   conditions on all the prefix keys that precede the sort keys.

You should be able to work around the limitation by using the aggregation framework which can be instructed to use temporary files for its pipeline stage outputs if required via the `allowDiskUse: true` option:

```
db.getCollection('logs').aggregate([
    {$match: {'uid.$id': { 
        '$in': [
            ObjectId("580e3397812de36b86d68c04"),
            ObjectId("580e33a9812de36b86d68c0b"),
            ObjectId("580e339a812de36b86d68c09"),
            ObjectId("580e339a812de36b86d68c08"),
            ObjectId("580e33a9812de36b86d68c0a"),
            ObjectId("580e33bd812de36b86d68c11"),
            ObjectId("580e33c0812de36b86d68c13")
        ]}, levelno: { '$gte': 10 }
    }},
    {$sort: {_id: 1}}
], { allowDiskUse: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `objsLeftInBatch()`  method to determine how many object are left in batch and iterate over it.

You can override the size and limit of the cursor batch size using `cursor.batchSize(size)`  and `cursor.limit(limit)`

Comment: i'm not really looking for a solution, I just want to understand why this isn't working as it was expected to

Comment: The MongoDB server returns the query results in batches. Batch size will not exceed the maximum BSON document size. 
For most queries, the first batch enough documents to exceed 1 megabyte. 
Subsequent batch size is 4 megabytes. To override the default size of the batch you use methods such as batchsize and limit